# Detect human faces in an immersive panorama image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, krpano

Is this possible to use a jQuery face-detection plugin (I'm using [this](https://github.com/jaysalvat/jquery.facedetection))
to detect human faces in an immersive 360 panorama image (I've used krpano 1.19-pr5 (build 2016-05-24) tools (demo version) to build the panorama files and krpano html5 viewer for rendering. You can download the whole package from [here](http://krpano.com/download/))?

The face-detection plugin works fine with simple 2D images and HTML5 canvases. The krpano viewer also renders the target panorama tiles in a canvas. Below is the code for the html file that renders the panorama image in browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>krpano - test_pano_3</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <style>
  @-ms-viewport { width:device-width; }
  @media only screen and (min-device-width:800px) { html { overflow:hidden; } }
  html { height:100%; }
  body { height:100%; overflow:hidden; margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="try-it">Try It</a>
<script src="test_pano_3.js"></script>

<div id="pano" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
 <noscript><table style="width:100%;height:100%;"><tr style="vertical-align:middle;"><td><div style="text-align:center;">ERROR:<br/><br/>Javascript not activated<br/><br/></div></td></tr></table></noscript>
 <script>
  embedpano({swf:"test_pano_3.swf", xml:"test_pano_3.xml", target:"pano", html5:"prefer", mobilescale:1.0, passQueryParameters:true});
 </script>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.facedetection.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function () {
    "use strict";

    $('#try-it').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.face').remove();
        
        var canvas = $("#krpanoSWFObject").find("canvas")[0];

        $(canvas).faceDetection({
            complete: function (faces) {
                console.log(faces);

                for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
                    $('<div>', {
                        'class':'face',
                        'css': {
                            'position': 'absolute',
                            'left':     faces[i].x * faces[i].scaleX + 'px',
                            'top':      faces[i].y * faces[i].scaleY + 'px',
                            'width':    faces[i].width  * faces[i].scaleX + 'px',
                            'height':   faces[i].height * faces[i].scaleY + 'px'
                        }
                    })
                    .insertAfter(this);
                }
            },
            error:function (code, message) {
                alert('Error: ' + message);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. Can you post your current solution somewhere that it is functioning? The code snippet here produces errors and no picture to start with.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var canvas = $("#krpanoSWFObject").find("canvas")[0];
```

should not work as find is not implemented in KRpano plugin. You should try this instead:

```
var canvas = $("#krpanoSWFObject canvas");
```

that returns the canvas element :)

Regards,